# Why is GitHub Actions unable to find rubocop and httparty gems?

Tags: ruby, github-actions, httparty, rubocop

I'm trying to develop a Ruby script that does some API calls using a couple of Classes that use the `httparty` gem in another rb file in a separate directory like this:

```
./script.rb
./lib
./lib/calls.rb
```

The code is actually more extensive but for the sake of simplicity here is a minimalist description:

script.rb

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require_relative 'lib/calls'

service = Service.new
response = service.get
puts response
```

lib/calls.rb

```
require 'httparty'

class Service
  include HTTParty
  base_uri 'https://api.service.com/v1/endpoint'

  def get
    self.class.get('/')
  end
end
```

That works great! Now I'm trying to run it using GitHub Actions and I get this error:

```
<internal:/opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.2.2/x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require': cannot load such file -- httparty (LoadError)
    from <internal:/opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.2.2/x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
    from /home/runner/work/test/test/lib/calls.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from ./script.rb:2:in `require_relative'
    from ./script.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

I've read somewhere about this issue happening if you use `require 'HTTParty` with caps but I'm using it with all lowercase, so that's not it.

Another interesting thing that I believe might be related to is that if I try to run `rubocop` directly in the command line in GitHub Actions I get this:

```
Run rubocop --parallel
/home/runner/work/_temp/b235a1be-84fe-430b-91fb-4118542d46a3.sh: line 1: rubocop: command not found
Error: Process completed with exit code 127.
```

Both `rubocop` and `httparty` have been installed, of course, and `rubocop` runs if I use `bundle exec rubocop`, but locally I can run it using just `rubocop`.

EDIT: yaml file from GitHub Actions and confirmation that the gems were installed:

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Install Ruby and gems
        uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1
        with:
          ruby-version: 3.2.2
          bundler-cache: true
      - name: Script
        run: ./script.rb
```

````
Run bundler install
...
Using httparty 0.21.0
...
Using rubocop 1.50.2
...
```
````

Comment: Please add your GHA workflow in your question. According to the description, both gems are not installed.

Comment: You're right @Azeem! Edited the question with that information. Thanks

Comment: Thanks! Looks like both gems are being installed during bundler run by the setup-ruby action. Please verify both before running your script, check both gems i.e. `gem list httparty rubocop`.

Comment: BTW, how are those gems being installed? You have a `Gemfile` also where they are listed? Please add that too. Also, is that script supposed to run independently? Or, is it part of the gem which should first be built to run?

Comment: I got no response from the Github Actions log when I run `gem list httparty rubocop`:

```
Run gem list httparty rubocop
  gem list httparty rubocop
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
```

And yes, I have a Gemfile and both gems are listed there. The gems in GitHub Actions are being installed by the `bundler-cache: true` line.

Comment: Tried also running `bundle check` and got `The Gemfile's dependencies are satisfied`
Also it's important to reiterate that this works in my local env.

Comment: Well, the installed gems should be there. Try `sudo gem list httparty rubocop`. `sudo` should not be needed but try anyway.

Comment: What is your local dev env like? Ubuntu? Using `rvm`? Ruby version?

Comment: Local dev is macOS 13, Ruby 3.2.2. 
When I'm saying that I got no results running `gem list httparty rubocop`, that's in GitHub Actions.

Comment: Right. Yes, I got that. Please try configuring GHA workflow for macOS i.e. `macos-13`. See if that works.

Comment: you might give it a try https://github.com/ruby/setup-ruby#dealing-with-a-corrupted-cache

Comment: I found a solution (or a workaround?). It works if I use `bundle exec` before every command or ruby script in the Run section of the GitHub Actions workflow. Thanks for your input anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by using `bundle exec` before running a command in GitHub Actions.

```
 - name: Script
        run: bundle exec script.rb
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to set `bundler-cache: false`.

---

I encountered the same issue today, and I followed Google to come here.

Unfortunately, the solution for Alvaro's problem doesn't work for me. But fortunately, I think I may have found the reason: the issue lies with the setting `bundler-cache: true.`

I believe the error occurs as follows: when the Action uses `ruby/setup-ruby@v1`, it actually executes a `bundle install` command inside, and the Action **caches the results** of this installation. Then, both Alvaro and I run `bundle install` again below, but this time the command only reads the cached results and doesn't actually install anything. As a result, the error about the missing gem occurs when running ruby run script.rb.

so, the solution is to set `bundler-cache: false`.